# Javascript Using callback in Array Method with .map

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, callback

I have this exercise I need help understanding where I am going wrong. Here is my code so far.

```
// Exercise Two: In this exercise you will be given an array called 'cents'
// This array is a list of prices, but everything is in cents instead of dollars.
// Using the map method, divide every value by 100 and save it as a new array 'dollars'

function exerciseTwo(cents){ 

    function mapMethod(array, cb) { // created the map method
      let dollars = [];   // declaring the new array 'dollars'
        for (i=0; i < array.length; i++) { //iterating through the loop
          let updatedValue = cb(array[i] / 100); // dividing the iteration by 100
          dollars.push(updatedValue); //pushing the updated value to the new array 'dollars'
         }
          return dollars; 
    }
        // Please write your answer in the lines above.
          return dollars; // getting error that 'dollars' is not defined :(
}
```

Comment: You should use the native js [`map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Assignments aren't usually arbitrary; your instructor, tutorial, or course will have covered the necessary topics to make it possible for you to do this. **Review your course materials, class notes, etc., and give it a try.** *If* you run into a *specific* problem, research it thoroughly, [search thoroughly](/help/searching), and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the specific problem. People will be glad to help.

Comment: You're not calling your function `mapMethod` anywhere in your code, and also dollars is defined in `mapMethod` scope not in `exerciseTwo` scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should distinguish between declaring and call a function.

```
function square(x) {
  return x*x;
} // <-- This is declare  

square(3) // <-- This is call
```

And what you did in the code above is just declare a `mapMethod` function inside the `exerciseTwo` function, which will get called when the system run test. But your `mapMethod` function will not get called, just defined only.

The inner function can use variables of the outer functions, but not vice versa. Then you cannot return `dollars` which declared in inner function `mapMethod()` from outside function `exerciseTwo()`

Follow the requirement. You should simplify your code with [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

```
function exerciseTwo(cents){
  const dollars = cents.map(cent => cent/100)
  return dollars
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was severely overthinking this. I do want to know why you used a 'const' variable instead of 'var' or 'let' though.The other explanations I went through various sources all seemed to lean towards 'let'.

Comment: First `var` is function scope, `let` and `const` for block scope. And it recommends using `let` and `const` instead of `var`. You can search on the internet why. Second, I use `const` for immutable data, it will prevent you from re-assign the `dollars` variable. `const a=[1,2,3]; a =[4,5] ~> cause error` but `let` will not. That why I used `const`

Answer (score 0):

-You have this error because you are trying to return dollars and dollars does not exist on your main function, this is not valid:

```
let updatedValue = cb(array[i] / 100);
```

do this:

```
let updatedValue = cb(cents[i] / 100);
```

but you don't see cents because you don't declare it inside the function

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this platform

Comment: No big deal. I added the spaces to format the code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the preferred code, written by the author. There are obviously more "ways to skin a cat".

```
  const dollars = cents.map(function(price){
return price/100;
```